# Loop in Google App Script, loop stops, loop not complete all

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill
I am using Google Apps Script

I have a Google Sheet where column A has 50 link Url (50 rows)
my below script works absolutely fine when it run demo.

However, the problem is that my loop stops but no error message
when i set my trigger run 5 minutes/time and check history execution times.

The loop does not complete all 50 times, sometimes once, sometimes 49 times.

I expect it to be running till the last row (50) regardless of the result.
Can you help?

**My Script**

```
async function getJSON() {
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const data = sheet.getRange("A1:A50").getValues()

for (var i = 1; i <=data.length; i++) {
  try {
  console.log(i)
const url = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()    
const content = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText("UTF-8");
const obj = JSON.parse(content);
 ....
  ...

} catch (e) 
 { continue;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your whole script, in your situation, when you remove "try - catch" and test it again, what result will you obtain? In that case, can you see the error message?

Comment: @Tanaike i want to loop 50 times so i don't want any error and i use try...catch

Comment: I set my trigger 5 minutes / time.

Comment: And when i check history, out put console.log(i). 50 times, sometimes 30 times, sometimes once,....  the loop is broken. 2.478 seconds total runtime

Comment: Why not include console.log(e); continue; in your catch block?  See what the error is.

Comment: @TheWizEd i don't care this problem. My problem is loop break. I use try...catch

Comment: Right now your catch is throwing away any errors.  All I'm saying is add a console.log() before your continue to see what the error is.  Maybe its not what you think it is.  This is similar to @Tanaike suggestion which forces an error message to the execution log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point I was trying to make is if you do not include a console.log() or Logger.log() in your catch block you wouldn't know if or what error occurs.

Script without console.log()

```
function test() {
  let a = 1;
  for( let i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    try {
      console.log(a/(b-i));
    }
    catch(err) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
7:43:21 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:43:22 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Script with console.log()

```
function test() {
  let a = 1;
  for( let i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    try {
      console.log(a/(b-i));
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
7:45:17 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:45:18 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: b is not defined]
7:45:18 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: b is not defined]
7:45:18 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: b is not defined]
7:45:18 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: b is not defined]
7:45:18 AM  Info    [ReferenceError: b is not defined]
7:45:17 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: It is result log : https://ibb.co/K6PKpqK

Comment: Debug [TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]

Comment: In the portion of the code you have shown I don't see any arrays indexed or objects indexed that would throw that error.  So its something that you haven't shown us.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  I found the problem